# Eclipse autobuilder on certain file extensions

Tags: eclipse, build-process, build-automation, auto-build

I'm setting up an Eclipse autobuilder to run the closure template compiler.  I've already got an ant task setup and running automatically whenever any file changes.  How can I set it up so that it only runs when I change a *.soy file?

I see that I can use a directory as a set of "relevant files," but my *.soy files may be scattered throughout the whole project.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with the Ant based builder. Instead you would need to implement your own incremental builder, extending the extension point `org.eclipse.core.resources.builders`. But as that would be a huge effort, the more efficient workaround might be to just filter in the Ant script itself.